# Length of input text field is not lining up with size

Tags: html, css, input

I have an input text box, and I am trying to have it be the exact length for the amount of text overlayed in the value field.  I have doubled checked that the size is the same length as the number of characters in the value field.  However, the input box is appearing shorter than the text.  The brackets are just php echos in Laravel Blade syntax.  The code is below:

HTML:

```
<div class="fan-name-change">
<input type="text" size="{{$name_length}}" class="fan-name" autocomplete="off" value="{{$fan->first_name}} {{$fan->last_name}}" id="user_name" name="user_name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fan-name-change {
    margin: 31px 0 0;
    display:block;

}

.fan-name-change input[type="text"] {

    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: rgba(50, 50, 54, 0.5);
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 27px;
    margin:0 auto;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS.  So

```
style="width:{{$name_length*$fontSize}}px;"
```

edit: sorry, missed some out!

Comment: Using em...or pixels?

Comment: This is too long.  It appears nearly twice as long as the text inside when I do this.